# How to extract from rxJava and put it on realm offline database?

Tags: android, realm, rx-java, retrofit2

I need to download a long list of 30k airports and put it on a offline database.

I made this code to download the json from the web:

```
 bFetch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(GithubService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT).build();

            GithubService service = retrofit.create(GithubService.class);

            service.getAirport()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Airport>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted()
                        {
                         bClear.setText("OK");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(List<Airport> airports)
                        {
                         Log.d("msh",String.valueOf(airports.size()));

                        }
                    });

        }
    });
```

and it works very well, but if I want to extract only one object, like map or a flatMap, it gives me this:

```
service.getAirport()
                    .map(new Func1<List<Airport>, Airport>() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public Airport call(List<Airport> airports) {
                            return null;
                        }
                    })
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Airport>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted()
                        {
                         bClear.setText("OK");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(List<Airport> airports)
                        {
                         Log.d("msh",String.valueOf(airports.size()));

                        }
                    });

        }
    });
```

with the error:

> Cannot resolve method 'subscribe(anonymous
>   rx.Subscriber>)

so:

1. what I have to do to solve it? My problem is that I don't understand very well rX and I have also a bit confusion
2. could I put data in realm database in map() method (if it works)?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/3187/realm/14393/using-realm-with-rxjava#t=201608051116154137207

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I don't understand how to do another subscription and where

Comment: Well where are you using the data from the Realm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're mapping from a `List<Airport>` to an `Airport`, you need to have a                     `Subscriber<Airport>` instead of `Subscriber<List<Airport>>`, along with the same change to the `onNext` method.

Comment: I've thought to do this but it gives me an error..maybe because it's not correct the way I've used to implement the map

Answer (score 0):

looks like it would compile with Java8 and RxJava2-RC5. I changed subscriber param from List to X and the onNext method from List to X. Maybe you coulde provide some more intel on your environment. Please notice that returning null is not possible anymore in RxJava2.

Furthermore notice that using newThread-Scheduler is not a good idea.

> This scheduler simply starts a new thread every time it is requested
>   via subscri beOn() or observeOn() . newThread() is hardly ever a good
>   choice, not only because of the latency involved when starting a
>   thread, but also because this thread is not reused. --Tomasz Nurkiewicz from "Reactive Programming with RxJava"

Example-Impl with RxJava2-RC5

```
Observable.just(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"))
                .map(new Function<List<String>, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String apply(List<String> s) throws Exception {
                        return null;
                    }
                }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String value) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
```